# What is different between (noun noun) and (adjective noun)?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

For instance

- "**Study Material**" vs "**Studying Material**"
- "**Participle Phrase**" vs "**Participial Phrase**"

Comment: In noun phrases like "study material" the first noun generally specifies the second somehow. So you know that this material is for study. Consider "roast chicken"; we have a chicken, and the leading noun shows us that it's been roasted. Now consider "roasting chicken"; used as an adjective, this tells us that we have a chicken which is currently being roasted. Apply that to "studying material" and it's nonsense, because material can't study. That said, you could still arguably use "studying material" as a noun phrase where you're basically talking about material for studying.

Comment: A noun used this way is an adjective use, so that it's really an adjective and not a noun any more. The OP may have had a more complex idea when asking this question, though.

Comment: @Kris: it is still a noun, actually. For example, we can modify nouns by adjectives like "study" --> "independent study", and this applies also to attributive nouns as in "study material" --> "independent study material." If "study" had stopped being a noun in the second phrase, we wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: @JohnClifford. Thanks for your explanation. I just confused about "study material" that was the same meaning as "studied material" (a material which is used for studying)? 

For this case, i am wrong about Active and Passive usage by myself.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for explanation. I was so confused when I found some unknown words and i always think "Why I have to use this? Why I can't use this instead?", such as natural language (not nature language), nitrogenous gas (not nitrogen gas).

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between [noun noun] and [adjective noun] is that a [noun noun] form is a word (specifically, a noun) and [adjective noun] is a phrase (an N-bar).  You can very often tell them apart by stress, since the word usually has stress on the first part, [nOUn noun], and the phrase usually has stress on the second part, [adjective nOUn].

- In *We'll [study matErial]*, with end stress, it's a verb phrase
- In *We need more [stUdy material]*, with fore stress, it's a noun.
- In *[Studying matErial] is no fun*, with end stress, it's a noun phrase.
- In *Some [stUdying material] is boring*, with fore stress, it's a noun.